# Model values are not binding with editor Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

My text editor model value is not binding which is of type textarea as well, and I have html formatted text in it. When I call my save method, this editor's model variable is null. I am not able to understand why this is happening as model with simple input type text is working fine, what could be the issue with the text editors model. Following is my code kindly have a look at this, may be I am doing something wrong.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="TemplateName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Template Name">                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea cols="18" rows="40" class="wysihtml5 wysihtml5-min form-control" id="templateDescription" ng-bind-html="TemplateDescription" placeholder="Enter Agreement Template ..." ></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And this is my controller code:

```
$scope.Template = {
            Name: $scope.TemplateName,
            Description: $scope.TemplateDescription,                
        };

       var promisePost = templateService.post($scope.Template);
            promisePost.then(function (pl) {

                //success message

            }, function (err) {

                //error message

            });
```

Comment: what not binding excatly. 'TemplateName' or 'TemplateDescription'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ng-model` and bind it directly to `Template.Description`

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
    <textarea cols="18" rows="40" class="wysihtml5 wysihtml5-min form-control" id="templateDescription" ng-model="Template.Description" placeholder="Enter Agreement Template ..."></textarea>
    {{Template.Description}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function sampleCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.Template = {
    Description: ''
  };
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sotbLmo0/) for your reference

Comment: thanks for your time, but this isn't working for me as this contains raw html as well so it gives me model as undefined.

Comment: can you a create a fiddle that show what you're saying?

Comment: your answer also helped and finally caught the issue, the editors scripts were ruining all party,

Answer (score 1):

yes use  `ng-model` for binding

html as

```
div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" ng-model="TemplateName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Template Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <textarea cols="18" rows="40" class="wysihtml5 wysihtml5-min form-control" id="templateDescription" 
  ng-bind-html="TemplateDescription" 
  ng-model='TemplateDescription' // add ng-model
  placeholder="Enter Agreement Template ..."></textarea>
</div>
```

here is the [plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7VundDyFa9gxPy21fEk2?p=preview)

Comment: my editor contains raw html and this returns me undefined

Comment: i checked, its binding. not sure what is ur exact issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-model` instead of `ng-bing-html`

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="TemplateName" 
       class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Template Name">                            
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea cols="18" rows="40" 
      class="wysihtml5 wysihtml5-min form-control" id="templateDescription" 
      ng-model="TemplateDescription" 
      placeholder="Enter Agreement Template ..." ></textarea>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Check my pen http://codepen.io/keephacking/pen/kXVjOX?editors=1010